# How to stop asynchronous flow in mule

Tags: multithreading, groovy, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I am trying to stop asynchronous flow in mule by using muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('').stop() command in groovy script, but even after it still triggering the flow.I want stop it abruptly.

Comment: Pls share your full Mule config file to detect the issue and to check what you have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
eventContext.setStopFurtherProcessing(true)
```

or

```
<expression-component>
    app.registry.yourflowName.stop();
  </expression-component>
```

if you are looking to stop the messages to go to your flow, you can also use filters.